# how to make button insert tag in a textfield?

Tags: javascript, textarea, addition

I'm trying to make multiple buttons that when clicked they add tags like `<p></p>` and `<b></b>` to a text-field. I have already figured out how to make it work like this:

```
<script>
function addtxt(input) {
    var obj=document.getElementById(input)
    obj.value+="<p></p>"
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="<p></p>" onclick="addtxt('body')">
```

but instead of having multiple scripts for every different button, I'd like to know if there is a way of the JS use the element `value` as `obj.value`. Is it possible?

EDIT: i found this other code online that's even better, how can i make this new code use the      element `value`, is there any way?

```
function boldText(textAreaId, link) 
{
    var browser=navigator.appName
    var b_version=navigator.appVersion

    if (browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer" && b_version>='4')
    {
        var str = document.selection.createRange().text;
        document.getElementById(textAreaId).focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = "<b>" + str + "</b>";
        return;
    }

    field = document.getElementById(textAreaId);
    startPos = field.selectionStart;
    endPos = field.selectionEnd;
    before = field.value.substr(0, startPos);
    selected = field.value.substr(field.selectionStart, (field.selectionEnd - field.selectionStart));
    after = field.value.substr(field.selectionEnd, (field.value.length - field.selectionEnd));
    field.value = before + "<b>" + selected + "</b>" + after;
}
```

Comment: were do you want to put the new tags?

Comment: to a text-area called body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass `this` to your `onclick` handler, and then access it's value within your function:

```
<script>
function addtxt(input, button) {
    var obj=document.getElementById(input);
    obj.value+=button.value;
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="<p></p>" onclick="addtxt('body', this)">
<input type="button" value="<b></b>" onclick="addtxt('body', this)">
```

Comment: that worked for me, but i found a new code, theres anyway to do the same with the new one?

Comment: Instead of passing `this` for each button, you can just pass the name of the tag as a string and build your tags within the function.

    `<input type="button" value="<p></p>" onclick="addtxt('body', 'p')">`

And at the end of your function, have it build the start and end tags:

    `field.value = before + "<" + tagName + ">" + selected + "</" + tagName + ">" + after;`

Comment: Would you mind explaining it a little bit more for a newbie? Should I exchange the `tagName`for something, I did the way you said and it returned "undefined"

Comment: You also need to change the names of your parameters for the function. it looks like it should be `function addtxt(textAreaId, tagName)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a specific `div` that receives the code javascript produces.
I don't recomend adding it to a `div` with `id` body, because that word is reserved for html structural elements, so I called the destination div "addHere".

**Javascript**

```
function addtxt(e) {
    console.log(e)
   var dest = document.getElementById("addHere");
   dest.innerHTML = e.value;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="<p>Text</p>" onclick="addtxt(this)">
<div id="addHere"></div>
```

[**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/QCeMT/)